# Python Pandas - cannot access df with applied filter

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the file with some df, but somehow, i can't access df with applied filter (i want to see data for only specific country - Poland)

I thought that maybe python don't read header as they are, but when i typed df.columns it showed me this name of the column in the list

[image]

and this is how i wanted to get it returned:

```
def test():
    file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mydeskop\test.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")    
    test = file.loc[file.loc['Country Name'] == 'Poland']
    return test
```

print(test())

And this is the error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [Country Name] is not in the [index]'
```

Comment: It has to be `file.loc[file['Country Name'] == 'Poland']`, you don't need multiple nested `loc`.

Comment: Can you try `test = file[file['Country Name'] == 'Poland']` instead of `test = file.loc[file.loc['Country Name'] == 'Poland']`

Comment: thanks, but the same:
KeyError: 'Country Name'

Comment: Can you edit your post and copy/paste the output of `file.columns` before running any filtering? You may have some extra whitespace in your column names. If that appears to be the case, try: `file = file.rename(columns=str.strip)` right after you read it in from your csv.

Comment: my bad! i changed the column names for forum's purpose and that is why your solution did not work - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:
Instead of :

```
test = file.loc[file.loc['Country Name'] == 'Poland']
```

do this:

```
test = file.loc[file['Country Name'] == 'Poland']
```

Through the 'loc' function, you will be selecting the rows, and through the column name inside, you're specifying the condition for selecting those rows. This should do the work I believe.

Comment: thanks, but i received still
KeyError: 'Country Name'
... like i have no clue, why the same thing is working in every other file but not this case..

Comment: Okay, um, do you need that ISO encoding in there?

Comment: yes i think i need, because there was some error previously with showing the data, however, i removed this and i can see the same KeyError

Comment: my bad! i changed the column names for forum's purpose and that is why your solution did not work - thanks!